# psych::alpha does not return mean, sd

Tags: r, psych

The `psych` package contains a function `?alpha` which calculates test reliability and some item statistics. When fed raw data (a data.frame with binary values for correct/incorrect answers), it returns, among other things, mean and st. dev. for each item. However, sometimes it doesn't, and only provides item-whole correlation.

Why is that?

[The docu](http://personality-project.org/r/psych/help/alpha.html) states that mean and sd are only calculated "For data matrices [...]", and that `x` is "A data.frame or matrix of data, or a covariance or correlation matrix". But how does it know whether I'm giving it raw data or a correlation matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `alpha` command of `psych` detects if the input `x` is a correlation matrix using the `isCorrelation` command.
Let consider the dataset given in this [tutorial](http://personality-project.org/r/r.guide.html#alpha):

```
datafilename <- "http://personality-project.org/R/datasets/extraversion.items.txt" 
items <- read.table(datafilename,header=TRUE)    
df <- with(items, data.frame(q_262 ,q_1480 ,q_819 ,q_1180 ,q_1742 ))
```

The object `df` is a `data.frame` whose columns represent the responses to five items. The command `isCorrelation` (used inside `alpha`) correctly detect that this is not a correlation matrix:

```
library(psych)
isCorrelation(df)
[1] FALSE
```

If we calculate the correlation matrix of `df` and pass to `isCorrelation`, we get again a correct answer:

```
mtx <- cor(df)
isCorrelation(mtx)
[1] TRUE
```

Looking inside `isCorrelation` one can see that a correlation matrix is defined as an object which is not a `data.frame` (hence, is a `matrix`) and which is symmetric:

```
isCorrelation <- function (x) 
{
    return(!is.data.frame(x) && isSymmetric(unname(x)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. This also means that less variance in raw data may result in incorrect classification (as it may happen to be symmetrical by chance). This would also mean that one has to convert to data.frame in order to prevent this outcome.

Comment: It is hard to imagine a data set so small that you would face the likelihood of the raw data being a symmetric matrix.  If you so few cases you probably should not be bothering to find coefficient alpha.